# xslt get xml value into input text box

Tags: xml, xslt, input

I'm not capable of getting my XML data into the XSLT. Im using the `literal return` function.

Here is my XML:

```
   <userproperties userid="82131">
   <following>1</following>
   <liked>1</liked>
  </userproperties>
```

Here are my attempts at getting the xml data into these values

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentlikedval" value="{//return/*/userproperties/liked}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="currentfollowingval" value="{//return/*/userproperties/following}"/>
```

And my second attempt:

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentlikedval" value="{//return/userproperties/liked}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="currentfollowingval" value="{//return/userproperties/following}"/>
```

And this is the resulting html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentlikedval" value=""><input type="hidden"     id="currentfollowingval" value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help knowing what the context is when you're doing this. If you want to use the absolute path (which will work in any context), then you should be doing:

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentlikedval" value="{/userproperties/liked}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="currentfollowingval" value="{/userproperties/following}"/>
```

(assuming that what you show is your entire XML).

> Im using the `literal return` function.

There is no such thing.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought the word return meant a literal function.  It seems to just be an example to an xml path

Comment: @jkushner I don't know what you mean by "a literal function". The word "return" has a special meaning in a [for expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-ForExpr) in XPath 2.0. When you use it in the way shown, as a location step, the stylesheet looks for an element named "return".